# Local navigation for long mobile web pages?

Tags: mobile, navigation, scrolling, header

I have a long (possibly, around 2500-3000px) mobile page which content is divided into three sections. The page has a header for global navigation. I am now wondering should I have a subheader for local navigation for these three sections.See image below.

[image]

Is this type of local navigation a good idea and if so, when it should be used (e.g., how long the page should be)? Also, if a subheader is used should both headers collapse when the page is scrolled down?

There is already a similar question about this, but it did not clearly answer my problems about page length and the overall necessity of subnavigation in mobile web pages.

Link: [Mobile global/sub navigation for a long scrolling page?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/98045/mobile-global-sub-navigation-for-a-long-scrolling-page)

Furthermore, I would appreciate  if there are any good examples of local navigation on mobile web.

Answer (score 3):

Having a submenu on a mobile screen is a very challenging task to accomplish. The type of menu you have shown in your mockup reduces the user experience. The header and a subheader consume most of the space from the top of a mobile screen. We have to be careful while playing around with mobile screens.

I would suggest having a hamburger menu in the header that has a tray menu sliding from top or from left which can be used to accommodate most of the menu contents like in the following image.

[image]

You can find the tutorial in this link https://www.rsjoomla.com/blog/view/337-template-tutorial-make-navigation-on-mobile-friendly-with-sub-menu-opening-button.html

I see Wikipedia mobile site has a very good example of placement of long contents in a very user-friendly way. the collapsable sections make the website more mobile friendly and keep the user away from long scrollings. It is best suited for you if your site have a lot of text content.

[image]

Comment: This post https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/99554/what-are-some-examples-case-studies-of-apps-that-did-better-due-to-improved-ux contains a link to a study showing that the hamburger menu significantly reduces the interactions with anything hidden behind the hamburger. Beware!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, especially the wikipedia example! Funny, a page that I view almost daily and did not realize that it could answer my problem..

In my UI, I have a hamburger menu in the header bar. Putting a local navigation options for the page with sub-header like in your example is a bit problematic. This because my system has a lot of different stories/pages (e.g. similar to wikipedia articles) with the same 3 section structure, but different content.